# Xceed GridControl

Tags: c#, xceed-datagrid

I have an Xceed gridcontrol, with a GroupByRow control on there.  When the groups are populated, the GroupByRow width, is only as width as the columns on there.  There does not seem to be an option to expand the width to the size of the actual gridcontrol.

Does anybody know a way around this?

Comment: Hey John,

I would suggest the fastest way of getting an answer when you have an issue with a 3rd party component - ask their customer support. Often they will be actual developers and you will get your answer from teh source. At the same time, you may not have many people on StackOverflow that use this particular grid.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest setting the last Column Width to * so that you can stretch the last Column to the end. This should stretch the GroupByControl all the way to the end of the DataGridControl.

Answer (score 0):

Is the source code for the control available to you? A little tweaking of the Datagrid style resources might help.

Either ways, I guess you could try binding the width to some other control with 'predicatable'(term used loosely) width.

Assume, the `DataGrid` is contained within a `Grid` named "gridContaingDataGrid", Then..

```
<GroupByRow  Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=gridContaingDataGrid}" .../>
```